# Magento Catalog Price Discount rules not apply in Product detail page

Tags: php, javascript, magento

I need some help, I have a project which is realized with Magento. On website on applying Catalog Discount in % the discounted price is shown in the product list page but in the Product View or Product Detail page it shows only Normal Price (non-discounted)...

Can you please guide me how to show discounted price in Product Detail page?

Comment: what does this have to do with cakephp?

Answer (score 17):

If anyone else comes across this, the answer is that you need to re-apply the rules and then refresh all the caches. The fails of the cache system rear their ugly head once more.